# Send data, query a table based on that data and render

Tags: python, django, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a spatial data infrastructure. It's based on a webapp created with Django. The webapp has a map, you can draw polygons on it. Based on the polygon you drew, specific data should be returned to the client.

So the flow looks like this: you put points on the map, it becomes a polygon after the third point. You press a button which triggers a putData js function and sends data to the appropiate view with a GET request & the view puts the data in a postgres datatable. All fine until this point.

In the putData function's success callback I specify another get request, without data. The view which handles this request gets the last row from the above specified postgres table, make queries to another datatable with the values from the last row and renders the result of the query with a html page. 
The problem is that the render never happens. The page where I pressed the button just stays like it is, and no redirect happens.

TL;DR: I want to put data in a postgres table with a get request, get values from that table with, query a second table and render a second html page with values I get from the second datatable.

**main.js**

```js
function putData() {
    //Biggest and lowest values from the arrays.
    console.log('YAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY');
    var maxX = Math.max(...boundingBox.X);
    var minX = Math.min(...boundingBox.X);
    var maxY = Math.max(...boundingBox.Y);
    var minY = Math.min(...boundingBox.Y);
    //AJAX request to getdata view with the four coorinates.
    $.ajax({
        url: "getdata/",
        type: "get",
        data: {'max_x': maxX, 'min_x': minX, 'max_y': maxY, 'min_y': minY},
        success: function () {
            console.log("Success!");
            $.ajax({
                url: "dowload",
                type: "get",
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Success!");
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

**get_data.py**

```
def get_data(request):
    maxX = request.GET['max_x']
    minX = request.GET['min_x']
    maxY = request.GET['max_y']
    minY = request.GET['min_y']
    extents = {
        'max_x': maxX,
        'min_x': minX,
        'max_y': maxY,
        'min_y': minY,
    }

    query = Query(max_x=maxX, min_x=minX, max_y=maxY, min_y=minY, username=username)
    query.save()
    return HttpResponse(extents)
```

**printdata.py**

```
def download(request):
    last_query = Query.objects.last()
    extents = {
        'max_x': last_query.max_x,
        'min_x': last_query.min_x,
        'max_y': last_query.max_y,
        'min_y': last_query.min_y,
    }
    """
    The **query** to the second datatable happens here.
    """
    return render(
        request,
        'output.html',
        context=query_result,
    )
```

Can you please tell me what could be the reasons for this? Am I missing something out?

I'm sure the callback function is not the best workaround for this problem, so I'm open for better solutions as well.

Comment: What do you see when you change your success functions to include: `success: function (res) {console.log(res);}`?

Comment: On the second success function I get the skeleton of the output.html, without the needed data. But in debug mode all data is correct, and it seems like the render is not okay. And no redirect of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to render the django template from ajax call for the second part of your question. I think its unnecessary. Try like this:

```
  url: "getdata/",
        type: "get",
        data: {'max_x': maxX, 'min_x': minX, 'max_y': maxY, 'min_y': minY},
        success: function () {
            console.log("Success!");
            window.location = '/download'  // will forcefully change the url of the browser to load the page.
        }
    })
}
```

Also the response from the first view should be a JsonResponse:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def get_data(request):
    maxX = request.GET['max_x']
    minX = request.GET['min_x']
    maxY = request.GET['max_y']
    minY = request.GET['min_y']
    extents = {
        'max_x': maxX,
        'min_x': minX,
        'max_y': maxY,
        'min_y': minY,
    }

    query = Query(max_x=maxX, min_x=minX, max_y=maxY, min_y=minY, username=username)
    query.save()
    return JsonResponse(extents)  # this is if you want to use these json data in Javascript
```

Comment: Thank you, this could be good. If I don't get better solutions, you'll have my upvote. But really my question is, why does render not work?

Comment: render works, you have seen it (as far as I read your comments in the question), but you are getting empty html because you are calling it via Ajax. So you need to go to that url  `<your_domain>/downloads/` to load the page.